# Excel VBA : Use the color of a shape in an If/Then case

Tags: vba, excel

I have created a chart on Excel using macros. Each of the shapes on the chart is filled with a color according to its category. I was wondering if it is possible to use the color of the shapes in an If/Then case to perform different actions, such as displaying the shapes with specific colors only.
For example, something similar to:

```
If shape.Fill.ForeColor.SchemeColor = 1 Then
   shape.delete
```

I have tried that, but it doesn't seem to do anything to my chart. Does anyone have an idea of how to do it?

Thank you !!

Comment: Did you try checking the color with the corresponding RGB value? Since SchemeColor depends on the current color scheme it might be looking for a different color than you'd expect.

Comment: Oh yes! I changed the color value to a RGB one and it works now. Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome! I've posted my comment as an answer so you can accept it and close the question. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try checking the color with the corresponding RGB value? Since SchemeColor depends on the current color scheme it might be looking for a different color than you'd expect